Download all Landsat tiles for a specific data range onto my computer using Google Earth Engine
I want to download all the available Landsat tiles (all bands included) for a given ROI using GEE. By tiles I mean the original tiles USGS uses to organize the Landsat data. I want each individual tile for say example May-01-2005, Oct-01-2005. I want to export every tile to specific folder on my computer.
Right now GEE mosaics the tiles first then exports them. I do not want this, I want as much data as possible for further GIS analysis later in say ArcGIS or QGIS.
Is this possible? Because I'd rather not have to use Earth Explorer. The region size is the United State Prairie Pothole Region (not the whole pothole region).

Welcome to the community! I have used geemap on Python to answer your question. Geemap is a Python package for interactive geospatial analysis and visualization with Google Earth Engine (GEE)
In addition, I have changed the dates you requested so that this answer can be reproduced quickly.
Be aware that you need to use an EARTHENGINE_TOKEN so that you can have access to the data. In case you use Jupyter Notebook or Google Collab, a pop-up window will show up in order to create the token.
import ee
import geemap

ee.Authenticate()
ee.Initialize()

start_date = '2005-05-01'
end_date = '2005-05-06'
# random region 
roi = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([-104.05, 49.05, -96.55, 45.05])

# Filter the Landsat collection
landsat = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LE07/C02/T1_L2").filterDate(start_date, end_date).filterBounds(roi)

# you may need to install geedim to download the data if it is not already installed
!pip install geedim

print(landsat.size().getInfo())
# 10 -  number of images found

# Create the folder if it doesn't exist
output_folder = 'Landsat_Tiles'
if not os.path.exists(output_folder):
    os.makedirs(output_folder)
out_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), output_folder)


# download images
geemap.download_ee_image_collection(landsat, out_dir, scale=30)


When you download the images you will see sth like that. The images you download are multi-band.

Regarding Landsat, you may have a look at the following link. Landat 7 is what you need based on the dates you specified.
https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/landsat

Thank you for your response. One of my mentors came up with code to use in Code Editor but I found that when I ran it the code editor crashed. I check how many tiles show up for the given region and it came back around 345 just for Landsat 5 and probably the same for Landsat 7. I will need to download both landsat 5&7 data and when I get to later years I will need Landsat 8&9 as well. I have an external drive with 4 tbs on it. When I translated to python it said I needed all my bands to be float or int? I just changed them to float and downloaded them, I dont know if that will be okay.

Just be aware of the fact that Landsat 8 launched in 2013 whereas Landsat 9 in 2021. Therefore, you cannot download images before these years respectively.

Using your method I keep getting an error even after I have installed geedim?
Exception: Error downloading image collection: Please install geedim using `pip install geedim` or `conda install -c conda-forge geedim```

I have installed geedim using conda and it has still not wanted to work?

I would recommend to create a new clean environment where you could install only the required packages (geemap, ee and geedim). There may be some conflicts with other packages.  Open your terminal:  conda create -n geo_env python=3.9 -> conda activate geo_env -> conda install -c -> conda-forge geemap ->
pip install earthengine-api
pip install geedim
